# Selenium Click different ID link

Tags: java, selenium

How can I click on different a elements with different id attribute values in Selenium Framework? 
Link ahref value are the same text.

```
<li>
<a id="abc_differentName_1_default_fun" href="javascript:startClient('abc_differentName_1', 'default', 'fun');">Start</a>
</li>

<li>
<a id="abc_differentName_2_default_fun"   href="javascript:startClient('abc_differentName_2', 'default', 'fun');">Start</a>
</li>

<li>
<a id="xyz_differentName_xyz_default_fun" href="javascript:startClient('xyz_differentName_xyz', 'default', 'fun');">Start</a>
</li>
```

I don't want to create every link one click method.

My problems are I don't want to create every link one click method. I want one click method depends on the id name. Possible to create a click method example: void clickByIdName(String idName) ?? 
Depends on which link i clicked, it will open new windows(other page object).

Many thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean `click on different ahref ID`? Do you mean `a` elements with different `id` attribute values?

Comment: Yes. I am thinking about to click on a element id, which are different on the page. All link text has the same "Start".

Answer (score 0):

You can use css selector to find all elements with id contain something like:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[id*=_differentName_]"))
```

If you want `void clickByIdName(String idName)`

```
void clickByIdName(String idName) {
    driver.findElement(By.Id(idName)).click();
}
```

Comment: ...and again- the closing bracket :)

Comment: I was waiting for your comment :)

Comment: Thanks. My problems are I don't want to create every link one click method. 
I want one click method depends on the id name. Possible to create a click method example: void clickByIdName(String idName) ??

Comment: I updated the answer with the method you wanted, but I would not recommend to use it. The code is too simple to wrap into a function.

Comment: Yes, and at least some basic `try/catch` should be within this method.

Comment: thanks! 
now I am using like here in my test cases. Do you think it is a bad test method/test code?
pageObject.clickByGameName("abc_gameName_default_funMode");
pageObject.clickByGameName("abc_gameName_default_moneyMode");

Comment: it depends on what you want. If the name `clickByGameName` helps you to read the test steps easier, then yes, you can use it. Just, if every game starts with `abc_gameName_default_`, I would put that part inside the `clickByGameName` method, then you can call `pageObject.clickByGameName("funMode")`

Comment: thanks again! my links could look like below:
abc_gameName_default_fun # 
abc_gameName_default_money # 
game name are different and fun/money mode are different
otherString_gameName_default_fun#
otherString_gameName_default_money#

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple links with similar text on page, you can use `id` value to select each element as follows:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a#abc_differentName_1_default_fun")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a#abc_differentName_2_default_fun")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a#xyz_differentName_xyz_default_fun")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks. My problems are I don't want to create every link one click method. 
I want one click method depends on the id name. Possible to create a click method example: void clickByIdName(String idName) ??

Comment: Yeah, try `public void clickByIdName(String idName) { driver.findElement(By.id(idName)).click(); }`

Comment: thanks! 
now I am using like here in my test cases. Do you think it is a bad test method/test code?
pageObject.clickByGameName("abc_gameName_default_funMode");
pageObject.clickByGameName("abc_gameName_default_moneyMode");

Comment: Each element (depending on tag) could have `id` attribute along with `name` attribute or could have just one of them or none of them. Using  `clickByGameName()` with `id` as argument could make some confusion. `clickByGameId()` can make more sense...but it's up to you :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use these ID attribute values to locate the link elements. There is a better way - a *link text* locator. You can locate all links with `Start` link text and choose which one you need getting it by index:

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.linkText("Start"));
links.get(0).click();
```

Comment: Thanks. My problems are I don't want to create every link one click method. 
I want one click method depends on the id name. Possible to create a click method example: void clickByIdName(String idName) ??

Comment: thanks! 
now I am using like here in my test cases. Do you think it is a bad test method/test code?
pageObject.clickByGameName("abc_gameName_default_funMode");
pageObject.clickByGameName("abc_gameName_default_moneyMode");

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's the exact problem here, but what is wrong with these:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("abc_differentName_1_default_fun")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("abc_differentName_2_default_fun")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("xyz_differentName_xyz_default_fun")).click();
```

Comment: thanks! 
now I am using like here in my test cases. Do you think it is a bad test method/test code?
pageObject.clickByGameName("abc_gameName_default_funMode");
pageObject.clickByGameName("abc_gameName_default_moneyMode");